# Bootstrap simple justfy-content:between or mr-auto not working

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

cant solve this simple problem,

1 - Why if I add a nav_element css idependent class and set the flex and justify-content:between to create space between the anchor tag and the div does not work?

2 - What should be this correctly approach in bootstrap?

3 - Do I need "d-flex" on navbar bootstrap property?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark d-flex w-100">
        <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand mr-auto">Gb32</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenu">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarMenu">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item navbar-el">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link" id="home__navbar">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item navbar-el">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link" id="about__navbar">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item navbar-el">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link" id="skills__navbar">Skills</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item navbar-el">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link" id="history__navbar">History</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item navbar-el">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link" id="contact__navbar">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Thanks guys! I will try to leave a fiddle, but I'm not sure the resources will keep.

https://jsfiddle.net/guibrother32/bn1qtfuc/2/

Comment: what you exactly want to do ? and if you are using bootstrap add in internally in fiddle

Comment: I added mate, I'm not sure why its not keeping when I try to share the url link. I'm trying to create space between the anchor tag and the div > ul. Like                      
Gb32 --------------------------------------------------------- About Skills History....

Comment: jsfiddle doesnot have can you tell me which boostrap cdn using ? you want be align in same line ? right now i can see div is below GB32

Comment: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js / https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js / https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css / https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js

Comment: added solution @Guibrother32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **never** update the bootstrap classes, you need to correctly use them.

You have to use `flex-grow-0` and `text-right` like below:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark d-flex w-100">
        <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand mr-auto">Gb32</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenu">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-grow-0" id="navbarMenu"> <!-- here -->
            <ul class="navbar-nav text-right"> <!-- here -->
                <li class="nav-item navbar-el">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link" id="home__navbar">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item navbar-el">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link" id="about__navbar">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item navbar-el">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link" id="skills__navbar">Skills</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item navbar-el">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link" id="skills__navbar">History</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item navbar-el">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link" id="contact__navbar">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Upvoting this because this is perfect answer, My answer was hack one.

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
  .ml-auto {
      left: auto !important;
      flex-basis:auto!important;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/csuzpq3o/

Comment: I saw it worked on jsfiddle mate, although it doesnt work on my project. Should I just add it on my css file?

Comment: just added it let me know what is issue coming. Dont forget to accept answer if this help you.

Comment: I deployed it, can you have a look? Not working on this application, not sure why https://gb32.herokuapp.com/

Comment: add this `flex-grow: initial`important;`  in `.ml-auto` this only add using media query for desktop.

Comment: Damn dude! Thats perfect! Fit like a glove! Can you try to explain me your thoughts? Want learn it. Check it there now

Comment: i tried playing with ml-auto css which is stopping me to align left side.

Comment: I see man, I should keep learning more and more flex-box. Again, good job! Thank you. Please edit your answer so somebody can use it as well.